# Html scroll box for div elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I have these "containers" which are essentially blocks with a title and sentence or two with a hover animation. Im trying to have multiple blocks proceed eachother vertically by scrolling down in only one area on the screen.

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 100px; overflow-y:auto;">
<div class="container">
                <div class="fancy_card">
                    <div class="card_text">     
                        <h3 class="title">Title</h3>
                        <div class="summary">
                            Content
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I've tried using overflow-y:auto, overflow:scroll, I've changed the height but I still can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, when I run your code it works for me. I am able to scroll through the different blocks while remaining inside the 100px height container. I tried on Chrome.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You want to hide the scrollbars???
Tour code works except on firefox and a </div> is missing...

Answer (score 0):

```html
   <div style="width: 300px; height: 100px; overflow-y: auto">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="fancy_card">
          <div class="card_text">
            <h3 class="title">Title</h3>
            <div class="summary">Content</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fancy_card">
          <div class="card_text">
            <h3 class="title">Title</h3>
            <div class="summary">Content</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fancy_card">
          <div class="card_text">
            <h3 class="title">Title</h3>
            <div class="summary">Content</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fancy_card">
          <div class="card_text">
            <h3 class="title">Title</h3>
            <div class="summary">Content</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fancy_card">
          <div class="card_text">
            <h3 class="title">Title</h3>
            <div class="summary">Content</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fancy_card">
          <div class="card_text">
            <h3 class="title">Title</h3>
            <div class="summary">Content</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fancy_card">
          <div class="card_text">
            <h3 class="title">Title</h3>
            <div class="summary">Content</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fancy_card">
          <div class="card_text">
            <h3 class="title">Title</h3>
            <div class="summary">Content</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This works already. You just need enough content to make it need to scroll.

Comment: Yea got it it was actually an issue in my css file for the cards thanks!